# Does the One Hive rule apply to preserving a continuous hive for your opponent as well?

Tags: hive

Here are the [rules](http://www.gen42.com/downloads/rules/Hive_Rules.pdf).

Page 9 lists the One Hive rule.

> The pieces in play must be linked at all times.

I'm looking for confirmation that this means my move must preserve my opponent's hive's continuity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've realized that my question was posted out of a misinterpretation of the rules that made me think that BLACK is one hive and WHITE is another, and that all white pieces had to be connected while all black pieces had to be connected. I realize now that the one hive rule pertains to all pieces regardless of color needing to be connected in one big happy family (with bickering siblings).